# I want to change div text using the text itself by javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change the text using javascript or jquery. When script will get the particular text, (ie., $) then it will change to USD. And again when script will get HK$, then it will change to HKD. This way I have to change many currency related text under the Currency class. This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="ItemSelctionZonePriceBox">
    <font class="Currency">$</font>
    <label id="ctl00_HotelsList_FinalPriceL_4" class="FinalPrice">1,749</label>
</div>
```

Another HTML code is:

```
<div class="ItemSelctionZonePriceBox">
    <font class="Currency">HK$</font>
    <label id="ctl00_HotelsList_FinalPriceL_4" class="FinalPrice">1,749</label>
</div>
```

I am very new in JS and jQuery, so please help me.

Comment: Don't use the tag `font`. It is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks cezar. I know font tag is deprecated in HTML5. but the html code is coming from third party. I have not written. and I can not change anything in the html code.

Comment: Please read about "onchange" or "JQuery.change()" and how to build switch function or hashmap and iterating over it in Javascript. It should help you to resolve your problem by yourself :)

Comment: The easiest way I think is to create a map/dict/hashtable(simply object in javascript) - 

     var conversion = {'$' : 'USD', 'HK$' : HKD, ... }

and then on whatever event you want to convert just do - 

var currency = $('.Currency');
currency.val(conversion[currency.val()])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery `.text()` property to get the value by `class` name and update them as necessary. Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zo4qdnbr/

```
 var $j_object = $(".Currency");
$j_object.each( function(i) {
    var type=$( this ).text();
if(type=='HK$')
$( this ).html( "HKD" );
if(type=='$')
$( this ).html( "USD" );
} );
```

Comment: Thanks prem89, its working fine but only in single div. When I am using more than one div then it's not working. This way:

<div class="ItemSelctionZonePriceBox">
        <font class="Currency">HK$</font>
        <label id="ctl00_HotelsList_FinalPriceL_4" class="FinalPrice">1,749</label>
</div>
<div class="ItemSelctionZonePriceBox">
        <font class="Currency">$</font>
        <label id="ctl00_HotelsList_FinalPriceL_4" class="FinalPrice">1,749</label>
</div>
<div>
...
...
</div>

Comment: Good point! You can use jquery's `each()` function to get this done. I have updated my answer with the same! Here is an updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zo4qdnbr/6/

Answer (score 0):

There are other & better ways to implement this but if you insist on using div's and changing div values :

To change text inside a div you can use .innerHTML of that element to check or change the value

```
document.getElementById("yourDIV").innerHTML = "new text value";
```

you can place your currency label inside a DIV with a name or id and change it afterwards (for example after page load)

```
<div class="Currency" name="CurrencyLabel">$</div>
```

This kinda script you run after page load then :

```
function changeCurrencyLabels()
{
    var x = document.getElementsByName("CurrencyLabel");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

        if (x[i].innerHTML=="$") {
           x[i].innerHTML="USD";
        }

        if (x[i].innerHTML=="HK$") {
           x[i].innerHTML="HKD";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks 4nti, I can't add currency label. I can't add or change anything in the html, because html code is coming from third party vendor. So I have to change it from outside through JS or Jquery. 
But I got a solution from your answer for my another problem. :)
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.  It finds the elements based on the class.

```
document.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.Currency');

    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if (x[i].innerHTML === '$') {
            x[i].innerHTML = 'USD';
        } else if (x[i].innerHTML === 'HK$') {
            x[i].innerHTML = 'HKD';
        }
    }
});
```